# Why T commutes with $(T-\lambda I)^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why T commutes with $(T-\lambda I)^k$?

When proving that a generalised eigenspace is T-invariant. The above property is used. However I don't understand why it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prove it via induction:

for the case $k=1$:$$
T(T-aI) = T^2 - aT = (T-aI)T
$$
and if $(T-aI)^k T = T(T-aI)^k$ then
$$
(T-aI)^{k+1} T=
(T-aI)^k (T-aI) T = (T-aI)^k T (T-aI) \\= T(T-aI)^k  (T-aI)
=  T(T-aI)^{k+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Induct on $k$. The base case is just to show that $T(T-\lambda I) = (T-\lambda I)T$. Of course, matrix multiplication is distributive over addition and $T$ always commutes with itself and the identity.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly write it out

$$(T-\lambda I)^k=\sum_{n=0}^k {k\choose n}T^n(\lambda I)^{k-n}$$

because $\lambda I$ commutes with everything.

Then mutliplying on the left or right by $T$ produces

$$\sum_{n=0}^k {k\choose n}T^{n+1}(\lambda I)^{k-n}$$

by linearity and (again) because $\lambda I$ commutes with all $T$.

Answer (score 1):

No induction needed!
$$T(T-\lambda I)^k=$$
$$=T(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I) \cdots (T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)T(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I) \cdots (T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)T(T-\lambda I) \cdots (T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)T \cdots (T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I) \cdots T(T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I) \cdots (T-\lambda I) T(T-\lambda I)$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I) \cdots (T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)T$$
$$=(T-\lambda I)^k T=$$

Comment: Pick a $k$, any $k$, and this is true.

Comment: this needs needs induction, even if it is the idea of, say, my answer.